# PHP consecutive subtraction two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, diff, subtraction, continue

I have 2 arrays like this

```
a = Array([101] => 5,[109] =>100,[220] => 50,[231] => 45,[245] => 90)
b = Array(['PRO'] => 12,['LOG'] => 15,['DEV'] => 100)
```

I want to consecutive subtract 2 array and result like this

```
c = Array([101] => 0,[109] => 0, [220] => 28, [231] => 45,  [245] => 90)
```

Explain:
I assumed used foreach to get value of a and b

```
1st: 5-12=0(move 7 to next time) <=> c[101] => 0;
2nd: 100-7 = 93 (7 at 1st)
3rd : 93-15 = 78
4th: 78-100 = 0 (move 22 to 5th time) <=> c[109] => 0
5th: 50-22 = 28 <=> c[220] => 28
```

But I don't know how to express in PHP

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, show us your code.

Comment: I don't have any code. :-(. But @vixducis helped me. It is right for me in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to rephrase your requirements, because I had to read your question about 10 times before I understood what you needed.

You want to reduce the values in `$a` (using subtraction) by consuming the values in `$b` in the order by which the associative elements occur.  When a value in `$b` is large enough to reduce the value in `$a` to zero or lower, you want to set the `$a` value to zero and carry the remaining value (difference) to the subtraction of the next value in `$a`.  This carried value must be consumed by one or more values in `$a` until it is depleted.  When a carried value is depleted, then the next occurring value in `$b` should be used to reduce the current value in `$a`.

- `12`(`$b[PRO]`) is used to reduce `5`(`$a[101]`) to `0`(`new $a[101]`) then `7` becomes the carried value and the next value in `$a` will be the new focus.
- `100`(`$a[109]`) is first reduce by `7`(`carried`) and becomes `93`(`new $a[109`).
- `93`(`new [109]`) is then reduced again by `15`(`$b[LOG]`) and becomes `78`(`new [109]`).
- `78`(`new [109]`) is then reduced again by `100`(`$b[DEV]`) flooring the value to `0`, making a new carried value of `22`, and moving focus to `$a[220]`.
- `50`(`$a[220]`) is reduced by `22`(`carried`) making `28`(`new $a[220]`).
- At this point, the carried value is depleted AND there are no more values in `$b` to reduce `$a` values by.
- `$a[231]` and `$a[245]` remain unchanged because there are no remaining values to subtract with.

My snippet uses text book arithmetic jargon: `minuend - suprahend = difference`.
The `$difference` is what is carried.
`array_shift()` is appropriate because it consumes the values in `$b` as they are accessed.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WkesI))

```
$a = [
    101 => 5,
    109 => 100,
    220 => 50,
    231 => 45,
    245 => 90
];
$b = [
    'PRO' => 12,
    'LOG' => 15,
    'DEV' => 100
];

$difference = 0;
foreach ($a as &$minuend) {
    while ($minuend && ($b || $difference < 0)) {
        $suprahend = $difference < 0 ? -$difference : array_shift($b);
        $difference = $minuend - $suprahend;
        $minuend = max(0, $difference);
    }
}
var_export($a);
```

Output:

```
array (
  101 => 0,
  109 => 0,
  220 => 28,
  231 => 45,
  245 => 90,
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It is ok for me. But I also need a array, what contain value combined a and b after subtraction. In this case I called it is d, and it look like this $d= ['PRO'=> array(101=>5,109=>7), 'LOG' => array(109=>15),'DEV'=>array(109=>78, 220=>22)]. What should I do?

Comment: Sounds like a new question.  Perhaps as a new question and include a link to this question as a reference.

Comment: Be sure to try to write code before you ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```php
$rest = 0;
foreach ($a as &$value) {
    if ($value < $rest) {
        $rest -= $value;
        $value = 0;
        continue;
    } else {
        $value -= $rest;
        $rest = 0;
    }

    while ($value > 0 && key($b) !== null) {
        if ($value < current($b)) {
            $rest = current($b) - $value;
            $value = 0;
        } else {
            $value -= current($b);
            $rest = 0;
        }
    
        next($b);
    }
}
```

Basically, this loops over the first array and in each loop:

- it first checks whether there was a rest value from the previous iteration, and lowers the value accordingly
- next, it'll loop over the second array from where it left off the previous iteration of the outer loop and lower the value until it reaches 0 or when the second array is 'used up'.

A working example can be found on [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/g49o0).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It is ok for me. But I also need a array, what contain value combined a and b after subtraction. In this case I called it is d, and it look like this $d = ['PRO'=> array(101=>5,109=>7), 'LOG' => array(109=>15),'DEV'=>array(109=>78, 220=>22)]. What should I do?